# Symfony2 - access form from a widget block template

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

Following is how the form is rendered.

```
<fieldset class="properties">
    {% block form_content %}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {% endblock %}
</fieldset>
```

Now I can access any form field in this template, like `{{ form.description }}`, it's all good . But here I have a collection field in this form, let's call it `collection`, I have built a custom field type for this, the block template for this custom type is `customCollect_widget`, everything until this point is fine, but if I want to access the collection object in this widget template, I got an error saying the field name does not exist in the form object.

Here's my widget template:

```
{% block customCollect_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for aa in form.collections %}
        <div>something</div>
        {% endfor %}
    ....
<% endblock %}
```

The problem, as I figured, is that the `form` isn't the same object that's passed to the code above. Is there any workaround to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, I solved it. In the collection type widget template, the `form` variable is referencing the form field type itself, in this case, the collection type. So to loop through the collection in the widget block, you just do `{% for child in form %}`.